# TikZ Drawing, Triangle, 2 Circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create something like this, anyone got any tipps or hints?

[image]

This is how far I've gotten so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2.82, 1.03) arc (-200: 60: 3);
\draw (-3, 0) -- (3, 0);
\draw (0, 0) -- (1.72, 0) -- (1.72, 0) -- (1.72, ); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Kind of having trouble with figuring out how to define angles and actually draw them in.

alpha = 72 degrees

beta = 144 degrees

alpha + beta = 216 degrees

I have to draw it precisely with the given measurements.

r (small radius) = 1.72

Any help would be great.

Comment: The is an angle pic available from the quotes tikzlibrary (see page 255 of manual).

Comment: beta can't be 144. It is clearly acute. Could you complete your code so we can compile it? (Add a document class, the `tikz` package and the `document` environment.)

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2.82, 1.03) arc (-200: 60: 3);
\draw (-3, 0) -- (3, 0);
\draw (0, 0) -- (1.8541, 0) -- (1.8541, 0) -- (1, -2.80) -- (0, 0);
\draw (1.8541, 1.03) arc (-200: 60: 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: You can use the `edit` link at the bottom of the post to add that to your question. That will make it easier for people to find it!

Answer (score 5):

The diagram shown cannot possibly be drawn with the dimensions specified. Beta is clearly acute. Alpha + beta cannot exceed 180. Moreover, if alpha is taken as 72, then r cannot be 1.72. So the smaller radius is still to be determined.

If R is 3 and alpha is 72, then beta must be 36, alpha + beta must be 108 and r must be about 1.8541. With these values, the diagram can be drawn. For example,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my alpha/.store in=\myalpha,
    my beta/.store in=\mybeta,
    my R/.store in=\myR,
    my r/.code={%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myr{\myR*(sin(\mybeta))/sin(\myalpha)}%
    },
    set alpha/.style={my alpha=#1, my beta=.5*#1},
    set R/.style={my R=#1, my r},
    set alpha=72,
    set R=3,
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily},
  ]
  \draw (-200:\myR) arc (-200: 60: \myR);
  \draw (180:\myR) -- (0:\myR);
  \draw [thick] (0,0) coordinate (o) -- (\mybeta:\myR) coordinate (a) node [midway, above] {R} -- (-\myalpha:\myR) coordinate (d) -- cycle node [midway, left] {R};
  \path (d) -- ++(\myalpha:\myR) coordinate (b) node [midway, right] {R} -- (a) node [midway, right] {r};
  \begin{scope}[angle radius=7.5mm]
    \draw [thick] (o) -- (b) node [midway, below] {r};
    \pic [draw, "$\beta$"] {angle=b--o--a};
    \pic [draw, "$\beta$"] {angle=o--a--b};
    \pic [draw, "$\beta$"] {angle=b--d--o};
  \end{scope}
  \pic [draw, "$\alpha+\beta$", angle radius=8.5mm] {angle=a--b--o};
  \pic [draw, "$\alpha$"] {angle=d--o--b};
  \pic [draw, "$\alpha$"] {angle=o--b--d};
  \draw [thick] (o) arc (180:.9*\myalpha:\myr);
  \draw [fill=white, thin, draw=green, >={Circle[black,fill=white,length=5pt,width=5pt]}, shorten >=-2.5pt,shorten <=-2.5pt, <->, fill opacity=.75, draw opacity=1] (o) -- (b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with modified dimensions]

Comment: Hey, nice of you to correct me, but may I ask for a bit of help. I find it hard to understand  your way of defining macros and how you used them throughout the code.

Comment: @militarschutze Take a look at the documentation of `pgfkeys` in the Ti*k*Z manual. The `\pgfmathsetmacro` is covered in the section on `pgfmath`, but the rest is just `pgfkeys`. `/.store in=\macro` is just a handler which stores the value passed in the relevant `\macro`. I don't know what else to say in general, but if you have a specific question you can't answer by looking at those sections of the manual, let me know.